# Differing results from angular function at different places in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

My code retrieves a list of permissions in the background and once those are retrieved, I want to either display the page or an error depending on if the user is permissioned.

What's bizarre is that I have two sections, page and error, one with ng-show matching the function which determines if the user is permissioned, and one with the negated function. But both page sections are showing.

If I change them both to be just the function itself - "isPermissioned" then the top one shows and the bottom doesn't, so it looks like they are getting different values from the same function. Could this be because one is executing before the other and when the background method updates the permissions, it isn't triggering the data binding? I suppose I am binding to a function, not a variable. How can I have the functions re-evaluate when something changes?

HTML is

```
<div ng-controller="SEFlexHomeController" ng-show="isPermissioned">
    <div class="row" id="TabsSet1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
                <li ng-show="AuthService.canRunFlexJobs || AuthService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs"><a href="#tabs-Jobs">Jobs</a></li>
                <li ng-show="AuthService.canViewFlexModels"><a href="#tabs-Models">Models</a></li>
                <li ng-show="AuthService.canAdministerFlex"><a href="#tabs-Administration">Administration</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-Jobs" ng-show="AuthService.canRunFlexJobs || AuthService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs">
                <h1>Welcome to this jobs tab</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-Models" ng-show="AuthService.canViewFlexModels">
                <h1>Welcome to this models tab</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-Administration" ng-show="AuthService.canAdministerFlex">
                <h1>Welcome to this administration tab</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="!isPermissioned">
    <h3>You have no permissions to view Secure Environment pages</h3>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller("SEFlexHomeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "$log", "$element", "$rootScope", "AlertsService", "AuthService", "SEApplicationService", function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $element, $rootScope, AlertsService, AuthService, SEApplicationService) {
        $rootScope.closeAlert = AlertsService.closeAlert;
        $scope.isDataLoading = false;
        $scope.AuthService = AuthService;
        $scope.show = false;

        $scope.isPermissioned = function() {
            return AuthService.canAdministerFlex || AuthService.canViewFlexModels || AuthService.canRunFlexJobs || AuthService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs;
        }
    }
]);
```

Auth service

```
function AuthService($log, $http) {

    var authService = {
        canRunFlexJobs: false,
        canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs: false,
        canViewFlexModels: false,
        canApproveFlexModels: false,
        canAdministerFlex: false
    };

    authService.getUserClaims = function () {
        $http.post("/Admin/Auth/GetUserClaims")
            .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                if (response) {
                    angular.forEach(response.data, function (item) {
                        if (item.Value === "SEFlexJobRunner")
                            authService.canRunFlexJobs = true;
                        if (item.Value === "SEFlexHighPriorityJobRunner")
                            authService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs = true;
                        if (item.Value === "SEFlexModelViewer")
                            authService.canViewFlexModels = true;
                        if (item.Value === "SEFlexModelApprover")
                            authService.canApproveFlexModels = true;
                        if (item.Value === "SEFlexAdministrator")
                            authService.canAdministerFlex = true;
                    });
                }
            })
            .error(function (reason, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(reason);
            });

    }
    authService.getUserClaims();
    return authService;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a function, you have to call it, at the moment, you're passing the function to the `ng-show` directive, and not the result of the function.

```
<div ng-controller="SEFlexHomeController" ng-show="isPermissioned()">
    <div class="row" id="TabsSet1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
                <li ng-show="AuthService.canRunFlexJobs || AuthService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs"><a href="#tabs-Jobs">Jobs</a></li>
                <li ng-show="AuthService.canViewFlexModels"><a href="#tabs-Models">Models</a></li>
                <li ng-show="AuthService.canAdministerFlex"><a href="#tabs-Administration">Administration</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-Jobs" ng-show="AuthService.canRunFlexJobs || AuthService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs">
                <h1>Welcome to this jobs tab</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-Models" ng-show="AuthService.canViewFlexModels">
                <h1>Welcome to this models tab</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-Administration" ng-show="AuthService.canAdministerFlex">
                <h1>Welcome to this administration tab</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="!isPermissioned()">
    <h3>You have no permissions to view Secure Environment pages</h3>
</div>
```

And also, instead of using `ng-show="!isPermissioned()"`, you can use `ng-hide`, like so: `ng-hide="isPermissioned()"`

**EDIT**:

Also, seems like your controller attribute should be encapsulating both `<div>`s:

```
<div ng-controller="SEFlexHomeController">
    <div ng-show="isPermissioned">
        ...
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="isPermissioned">
        <h3>You have no permissions to view Secure Environment pages</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made those changes but I'm still getting inconsistent results. Its definitely going into the function now and returning the result. I've even hard coded the function to just return "true". So there's no way the background results could be affecting it as I'm now returning a dummy true value always. But yet both DIVs are still visible?! I've tried with ng-hide as well, still the same. If I hard-code ng-hide="true" in the second div, it disappears. But ng-hide="isPermissioned()" when isPermissioned has been hard coded to return true lets the DIV still show!

Comment: Checkout my edit. Haven't noticed that before, but your controller should encapulate both DIVs as to share the same scope. At the moment, your second DIV exists in the parent's scope (which is most likely your root app scope at this point).

Comment: That's the puppy! Wow this scope thing can cause some totally messed up results. It works perfectly now, thanks. And of course now you explain it like that of course that's what it was doing, calling the method in a different scope so it had different values. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating all the module registering in Immediately executing function to avoid creating global variable references.

Sample as below

```
(function(){
//Your angular code goes here(i.e service or module)
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the isPermissioned method, so ng-show="!isPermissioned will be ng-show="!isPermissioned() and ng-show="isPermissioned" will be ng-show="isPermissioned"()